# TabPageCollection.RemoveByKey index 0 out of range

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

So I've got a really weird issue.  I'm developing a chat application using the jabber framework.  I'm trying to remove a TabPage from a TabControl (removing a chat tab from the chat window).  Each TabPage is keyed by the string of the user's JID (user@server.com).  Whenever I try to remove a TabPage by its key, I get an ArgumentOutOfRangeException.  Below is the code I have for explicitly removing the chat tab.  I have another function that listens to the closing event of the form itself, that simply removes the first (and only) control from each TabPage before allowing the form to close.

The weird part is that this code works fine when the chat form hasn't been closed.  Each chat tab can be explicitly removed using this function.  The problem arises when I go to remove a tab after the form has been closed and reopened (with the current-open chats being re-added in their own tabs).

Some key things to know:

- I can successfully retrieve the index of the TabPage I want to close through `chatTabs.TabPages.IndexOfKey(...)`
- I can successfully retrieve the TabPage object itself through `chatTabs.TabPages[...]` using the index value from `IndexOfKey(...)`
- When I try to remove the page by passing the value from `chatTabs.TabPages[...]` into `chatTabs.TabPages.Remove(...)`, nothing happens
- When I try to close the form in the `catch` block, nothing happens, and the form stays open

Clearly this is a very weird issue, and I've run out of ways to debug it.  Any ideas SO?

`RemoveChat(...)` function:

```
private void RemoveChat(JID userJID)
{
    if (chatTabs.TabPages.ContainsKey(userJID.Bare))
    {
        try
        {
            // remove the chat tab
            if (chatTabs.TabPages[userJID.Bare].Controls.Count > 0)
            {
                chatTabs.TabPages[userJID.Bare].Controls.RemoveAt(0);
            }
            chatTabs.TabPages.RemoveByKey(userJID.Bare);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.Error(ex.Message + "\r\n" + ex.StackTrace);
            this.Close(); return;
        }

        // select the first available chat tab
        if (chatTabs.TabCount > 0)
        {
            chatTabs.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
        // close the chat window
        else
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Form closing listener/handler function:

```
private void ChatForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    // remove each chat control so they do not get disposed
    foreach (TabPage tab in chatTabs.TabPages)
    {
        tab.Controls.RemoveAt(0);
    }
}
```

Error I get from `RemoveByKey(...)`:

```
2013-03-01 12:39:42,963: ERROR <10> [ChatForm] - Index 0 is out of range.
Parameter name: index
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlCollection.get_Item(Int32 index)
   at System.Windows.Forms.TabControl.TabPageCollection.RemoveByKey(String key)
   at <...>.ChatForm.RemoveChat(JID userJID) in c:\Work\[...]\ChatForm.cs:line 87
```

where line 87 is the call to `RemoveByKey(...)`

Comment: You are trying to remove `Control`, but there's none.